# Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse?

Tags: alamofire, alamofireimage

It is giving me the Error: Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse?'
It should be caused by @escaping but I cannot make it work in the sentence below. Please help, Swift 3.0, AlamofireImage.
There are other similar answers but cannot make them work with my code below.

```
func getNetworkImage(_ urlString: String, completion: @escaping ((UIImage) -> Void)) -> (ImageRequest) {
    let queue = decoder.queue.underlyingQueue
    let request = Alamofire.request(urlString)
    let imageRequest = ImageRequest(request: request)

    imageRequest.request.response(
        queue: queue,
        responseSerializer: Request.imageResponseSerializer(),
        completionHandler: { response in
            guard let image = response.result.value else {
                return
            }
            let decodeOperation = self.decodeImage(image) { image in
                completion(image)
                self.cacheImage(image, urlString: urlString)
            }
            imageRequest.decodeOperation = decodeOperation
        }
    )

    return imageRequest
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error message: `Cannot call value of non-function type 'HTTPURLResponse?'` is telling you that the instance variable `value` can not be accessed. The bad thing is that it is telling you this in the wrong line of code. That may be the reason why it was so difficult to find.

The structure of the response object has changed. You code:

```
guard let image = response.result.value else {
            return
}
```

Won't work anymore because the `response` object is of type `DefaultDataResponse` not `HTTPResponse...`

In order to access the data/image you need to go with `response.response.` depending on what you want to access:

```
response.response?.value(forKey: "")
```

Check the other method calls and properties. I believe you will find the data you are looking for.

Comment: Thank you, I will look into it!